# FxCop integrator 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fxcop

- FxCopIntegrator-2.0.0
- FxCopSetup 10.0

I am using above tools to integrate `Fxcop` with `Visual Studio 2010` Professional Edition and it is worked fine as expected. Same configuration is not working in `Visual Studio 2012` professional edition.

Is there any tool/configuration/integrator available for `FxCop` integrating with Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio 2012/13  has fxcop built into the IDE.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Anuja :)